# Generating PDF with dompdf and getting empty space in the first tr after page break

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, dompdf

I have faced very weird bug when using `dompdf` for generating PDFs. Problem occures when page break takes place inside of the table. After the page break, first `tr` on the following page has some weird empty space on the left side (picture below shows the problem).

[image]

I have tried setting the `page-break-inside: avoid;` to avoid breaking the table, but that didn't solve the problem. In that case, empty space is being added to the same `tr` even if it's not the first `tr` on the page any longer.

Any suggestions on how to solve this and remove that empty space?

Comment: From what I remember: Scan the SAPI error diagnostic messages, especially on the WARNING and NOTICE levels (check `error_reporting`). Which SAPI are you using? If unsure you can also enable PHP error logging to file and check the error log file. Additionally you can try with _display errors_ if you've got a development machine (but it might interfere with PDF creation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem eventually. The weird behaviour was caused by `display: inline-block;` that was set on the some childs of the `td`. Removing `display: inline-block;`, and somehow rewriting the logic using `table`, fixed my problem.